# How to force visual studio code to do text search in all files, even binary file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext3

I have some log files, all are text file with UTF8 encoding.
Some of them contains embedded characters, like 0x3.

Visual studio code treat kind of these files as binary type and won't search their content in search in files mode. But since the files are text file in fact, it's fine to open them in visual studio by clicking.

I found same issue on sublime text v3. BBEdit 10+ able to search in this situation, but I used to VSC/ST3.

Is it possible to let visual studio code or sublime text, to treat all files in specific location/specific name as text file and do searching?

BTW, the file extension is .log, just incase someone mentioned kind of binary extension setting.

Comment: Notepad++ can search all files regardless of extension

Answer (score -3):

You could try unchecking this button marked in red

[image]

Comment: Since my purpose is to search text in text files, but VSC/ST3 thinks they are binary file. This feature can help my exclude files to be searching but can't help in search..